How to pass full values from the config.json file using Git file generator to custom plugin generator
I have been working with ArgoCD for sometime now and I have an issue I can't find the answer for:
config.json:
[
  {
    "carbon-ns": "carbon-genesis-ns",
    "carbon-app": "carbon-genesis-app",
    "versions": ["v1","v2","v3"]
  }
]

And I am using the following Application-Set to create applications in order to deploy my applications to Argocd:
ApplicationSet:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    manager: argocd-applicationset-controller
  name: carbon-app-template-appset
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - git:
      files:
      - path: carbon-applications/genpop/apps/sbx/sadc/application-manifests/config.json
      repoURL: ssh://git@test.git
      revision: master
  - plugin:
      configMapRef:
        name: version-generator
      input:
        parameters:
          config: '{{ .Values }}' ### <<-- content from config.json file is not getting substituted from git generator 
  syncPolicy:
    preserveResourcesOnDeletion: true
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{ carbon-ns }}-{{ carbon-app }}-{{ version }}-sadc-sbx-v1'
    spec:
      destination:
        namespace: '{{ carbon-ns }}'
        server: https://test.com/k8s/clusters/xyz
      project: sbx-cluster-v1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 1
      sources:
      - ref: values
        repoURL: ssh://git@test.git
        targetRevision: master
      - helm:
          parameters:
          - name: vaultport
            value: "443"
          releaseName: carbon-app-helm-test
          valueFiles:
          - $values/carbon-applications/genpop/apps/sbx/sadc/application-manifests/value-files/{{carbon-ns}}/{{carbon-app}}/{{ carbon-app }}-{{ version }}.yml
        path: 20240705-1.3.1/application-templates
        repoURL: ssh://git@test.git
        targetRevision: master
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: false
        syncOptions:
        - CreateNamespace=false
        - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true
        - Validate=true

Problem:
The content from config.json file is not getting substituted to input paramaters of input parameters from git file generator.
Output: is flatenned array which is coming properly for me if proper input is passed and applications are getting created in argocd.
{
    "output": {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "carbon-app": "carbon-genesis-app",
                "carbon-ns": "carbon-genesis-ns",
                "version": "v1"
            },
            {
                "carbon-app": "carbon-genesis-app",
                "carbon-ns": "carbon-genesis-ns",
                "version": "v2"
            },
            {
                "carbon-app": "carbon-genesis-app",
                "carbon-ns": "carbon-genesis-ns",
                "version": "v3"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Custom Plugin API Request logs: (Its going as .Values itself in request body :/ )
POST 400 /api/v1/getparams.execute? 23.313µs {"applicationSetName":"carbon-app-template-appset","input":{"parameters":{"config":"{{ .Values }}"}}}


I referred below links:
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Git/
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Plugin/
